# How do I calculate probabilities for an RPG game?

Tags: probability, game-theory

I want to create a probability calculator for an RPG.
I am not a professional programmer and definitely not a mathematician ;) I just want to challenge myself.

How do I go about the logic? The roll I want to make the calculator for uses a number of D6 dice and D12 dice, and the sum of dice in a roll must exceed the "target number". For example, I might roll 3D6 + D12, and the total must be at least 15.

Do I need to write a function that:

1. makes all the possible rolls for a combination of D12s and D6s
2. counts how many of these achieved the required result
3. divides the number of successful rolls by the number of all rolls, and the result converted to percentage is the probability?

If I want to treat a 12 on the D12 as an automatic success regardless of the other dice, where does that fit into this logic?

I know of anydice.com, but want to see if I can handle such a hobby project.

Comment: For clarification: Given a target number and a combination of D6es and D12s, you want to know the probability of either rolling at least that number OR rolling at least one 12? What tools do you intend to use?

Comment: Combinatorics and probability problems like the type described here can be notoriously tedious.  Using computer assistance is strongly recommended.  My recommendation is to use generating functions, here as $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^6)^3(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{12})$, expanding that out and looking at the coefficients.  The coefficients count how many sequences of dierolls lead to that as a sum.  Divide here by $6^3\cdot 12$ for the probability.  As for treating $12$'s on the d12 as an autosuccess, ignore the $x^{12}$ in the above and treat that case separately.

Comment: As for implementing a polynomial multiplier in code, depending on language there is probably a package for that.  Otherwise, it can be seen as a matter of utilizing arrays.  In either event, that is outside the scope of what this site is intended for.

Comment: Meaning of RPG ? Random (Polynomial/Poker/Pokemon...) Generator ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Probably "role playing game".

Comment: @David Mitra Thanks. A pity that it is not the asker who answers...

Comment: Math.SE is not generally responsive to "how does one program this" Questions.  If you look at this as a potential programming project, one of the first steps is to write down the expressions you need to evaluate.  There seem to be many variations (resp. the number of D6 and the number of D12, and the "target number") that can be combined in a single routine using call-by-value arguments.  Your challenge is to write a spec for yourself, and while you're at it, some test cases to validate your code.  None of this is on-topic for Math.SE.